# How to get same index value from other array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, compare

I have two arrays and i want to access data of same index value from  other array.

Two Array list :

```
ArrayList<Integer> Position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> List_Data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now my `Position` array contains Integer value like index of data `i.e 0,3,5 out of 10` Records.
i want to get only those string whose index should be  `i.e 0,3,5 out of 10` .

Example :

```
String Array >> [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J,K]; 

Index >> Now i am selecting 2 ,5 index data.

Final Output as string >> C,F
```

So at the end i get actual string from array.

I get [this](http://mantascode.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/twoarray.jpg) and some other link also but not get exact idea how to do this.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Why not try to fix your problems with using more suitable Collections such as Maps or simply ArrayList<Integer, String>

Comment: there are some other things with same operation. so its simply that get data according index

Comment: Your given example and linked image don't do the same thing. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not not saying that above code is wrong but its not working according my needs. or i can't handle because of my other code limitation.

Finally, I get as i want like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Poisition.size(); i++)
{

 System.out.println("Selected Data --->"+ List_Data.get(Poisition.get(i)));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, If I understand what you want correctly (otherwise let me know)

```
String sr=Lista_Data.get(Position.get(INDEX YOU NEED; EG 1, 5, 1000...))
```

Comment: get(Position.get(INDEX YOU NEED; EG 1, 5, 1000...)) here , what is Position ?

Comment: Position is your ArrayList that you called Position.

Comment: this operation i am doing inside button's click event. so get only list.get(int)

Answer (score 1):

You can get object from `ArrayList` using `get` function. Then you can use it as an index to another `ArrayList`.

```
String res = "";
for (Integer pos : Position) {
    res += List_Data.get(Position.get(pos));
}
```

Comment: i am not able to get Position in get(int index) ;

Comment: You first need to populate those arrays

Comment: What do you mean? you dont have Position ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is method `indexOf(...)` of `List`.

```
public String getStringByIndex(Integer index) {
    return List_Data.get(Position.indexOf(index));
}
```

Comment: i tried by this way spinner_Data.indexOf(posSel.get(i)); but force close